# Is it possible to include mutiple equations in a lambda function

Tags: python, lambda

I'm trying to include multiple operations in the lambda function with variables that have different lengths, i.e. something like:

```
$ serial_result = map(lambda x,y:(x**2,y**3), range(20), range(10))
```

but this doesn't work. Could someone tell me how to get around this?
I understand that:

```
$ serial_result = map(lambda x,y:(x**2,y**3), range(0,20,2), range(10))
```

works because the arrays of "x" and "y" have the same length.

Comment: So whats your expected output for first case?

Comment: I can't tell what indexing you want. In python3, maybe list(range(10)) * 2 would work to replace range(10) as the second argument -- at least it has the same number of elements as list(range(20)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the product of range items you can use `itertools.product` :

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> serial_result = map(lambda x:(x[0]**2,x[1]**3), product(range(20), range(10)))
```

If you want to pass the pairs to lambda like second case you can use `itertools.zip_longest` (in python 2 use `izip_longest`)and pass a fillvalue to fill the missed items,

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> serial_result = map(lambda x:(x[0]**2,x[1]**3), zip_longest(range(20), range(10),fillvalue=1))
```

Note that if you are in python 2 you can pass multiple argument to lambda as a tuple :

```
>>> serial_result = map(lambda (x,y):(x**2,y**3), product(range(20), range(10)))
```

See the difference of `izip_longest` and `product` in following example :

```
>>> list(product(range(5),range(3)))
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2)]
>>> list(zip_longest(range(5),range(3)))
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, None), (4, None)]
>>> list(zip_longest(range(5),range(3),fillvalue=1))
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 1), (4, 1)]
```

Comment: The lambdas require two arguments, but only get one. In Python 2 it's as easy as doing `lambda (x,y): (x**2,y**3)` instead. In Python 3 this doesn't work though.

Comment: @tyn In python 3.4.3, lambda x,y: (x**2, y**3) seems to work fine.  You can't put parentheses around the tuple, but otherwise it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be confused as to how exactly you want to use all the values in these two variables. There are several ways combine them...

If you want a result for every combination of an element in `a` and an element in `b`: `itertools.product(a, b)`.

If you want to stop once you get to the end of the shorter: `zip(a, b)`

If you want to continue on until you've used all of the longest: `itertools.zip_longer(a, b)` (`izip_longer` in python 2). Once `a` runs out of elements it will be filled in with `None`, or a default you provide.